# PHP MySQL Creating A Discussion Board

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently working on developing a discussion board. My issue is that it seems like it assigns each category the id of 4, and then displays the forums that are in category 4. (That's not explained very well, but hopefully you understand)...

```
<?php
  /* CATEGORIES */
    $query = "SELECT * FROM bkg_categories";
        try {
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute();
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = "An error has occured. Please try again later.";
        }
        $categories = $stmt->fetchAll();

        /* FORUMS */
        foreach($categories as $category) {
            $catid = $category['category_id'];

            $query = "SELECT * FROM bkg_forums WHERE category_id = :catid";
            $query_params = array(':catid' => $catid);

            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
                $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                    $error[] = "An error has occured. Please try again later.";
            }
            $forums = $stmt->fetchAll();

            foreach($forums as $forum) {

                print $forum['forum_id'];

            }

        }

        ?>
```

and the html to display it all onthe page.

```
 <?php foreach($categories as $category): ?>
            <div><?php echo $category['category_name']; ?><?php echo $category['category_id']; ?></div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tr> 
                    <td colspan="2">Forum</td>
                    <td>Lastest Post</td>
                    <td>Topics</td>
                    <td>Posts</td>
                </tr>
                <?php foreach($forums as $forum): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="5%"></td>
                        <td><a href="viewforum.php?f=<?php echo $forum['forum_id']; ?>"><?php echo $forum['forum_name']; ?></a></td>
                        <td width="15%">
                            <!--<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>
                                <a href="viewtopic.php?f=<?php echo $post['forum_id']; ?>&t=<?php echo $post['topic_id']; ?>#<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>"><?php echo substr($post['post_subject'], 0, 10);  ?></a>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>-->

                        </td>
                        <td width="5%" class="text-center"></td>
                        <td width="5%" class="text-center"></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </table>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
```

EDIT:

I created four categories

General
Development
Gaming
Off-Topic

and 1 Forum with the category_id of 4, and that 1 forum, is displayed in each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overwriting $forums each time.

You could do something like

`$forums[$catid] = $stmt->fetchAll();`

and then

`foreach($forums[$category['category_id']] as $forum):`